# Как выбрать вхождения из строки по меткам begin и end?

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения, строки, динамические-массивы

Есть файл с метками, который определяет структуру документа. Например:

```
<!-- begin-block-a-1 -->
Содержимое блока block-a-1
    <!-- begin-block-b-1 -->
    Содержимое блока block-b-1
         <!-- begin-block-c-1 -->
         Содержимое блока block-с-1
         <!-- end-block-c-1 -->
         <!-- begin-block-c-2 -->
         Содержимое блока block-с-2
         <!-- end-block-c-2 -->
         <!-- begin-block-c-3 -->
         Содержимое блока block-с-3
         <!-- end-block-c-3 -->
    <!-- end-block-b-1 -->
    <!-- begin-block-b-2 -->
    Содержимое блока block-b-2
    <!-- end-block-b-2 -->
    <!-- begin-block-b-3 -->
    Содержимое блока block-b-3
    <!-- end-block-b-3 -->
<!-- end-block-a-1 -->
<!-- begin-block-a-2 -->
Content in block block-a-2
<!-- end-block-a-2 -->
```

Можно ли при помощи регулярных выражений и функций PHP превратить такую строку в массив:

```
 array(1) {
  ["block-a-1"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "Содержимое блока block-a-1"
    ["block-b-1"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(41) "Содержимое блока block-b-1"
      ["block-c-1"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(42) "Содержимое блока block-с-1"
      }
      ["block-c-2"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(42) "Содержимое блока block-с-2"
      }
      ["block-c-3"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(42) "Содержимое блока block-с-3"
      }
    }
    ["block-b-2"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(41) "Содержимое блока block-b-2"
    }
    ["block-b-3"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(41) "Содержимое блока block-b-3"
    }
  }
}
```

Здесь метка **begin** сообщает о начале смыслового блока, а метка **end** сообщает о завершении смыслового блока.

Моя проблема заключается в составлении правильного регулярного выражения. Пишу так:

```
'~<!-- begin-(.?) -->(.*?)<!-- end-(.?) -->~s'
```

но в таком случае совпадение будет такое:

```
<!-- begin-block-a-1 -->
Содержимое блока block-a-1
    <!-- begin-block-b-1 -->
    Содержимое блока block-b-1
         <!-- begin-block-c-1 -->
         Содержимое блока block-с-1
         <!-- end-block-c-1 -->
```

А мне нужно такое:

```
<!-- begin-block-a-1 -->
Содержимое блока block-a-1
    <!-- begin-block-b-1 -->
    Содержимое блокаk block-b-1
         <!-- begin-block-c-1 -->
         Содержимое блока block-с-1
         <!-- end-block-c-1 -->
         <!-- begin-block-c-2 -->
         Содержимое блока block-с-2
         <!-- end-block-c-2 -->
         <!-- begin-block-c-3 -->
         Содержимое блока block-с-3
         <!-- end-block-c-3 -->
    <!-- end-block-b-1 -->
    <!-- begin-block-b-2 -->
    Содержимое блока block-b-2
    <!-- end-block-b-2 -->
    <!-- begin-block-b-3 -->
    Содержимое блока block-b-3
    <!-- end-block-b-3 -->
<!-- end-block-a-1 -->
```

И такое:

```
<!-- begin-block-a-2 -->
Содержимое блока block-a-2
<!-- end-block-a-2 -->
```

Т.е. нужно получать одинаковые группы регулярным выражением.

Comment: **Можно ли** - Можно. **Как можно** - рекурсивные регулярные выражения
http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.recursive.php
Но гораздо проще будет сделать свою собственную рекурсивную функцию =)

Comment: Т.е. рекурсивно выбираем тот кусок, который находится внутри меток и передаем его дальше в ту же функцию, которвая уже внутри вырезает содержимое меток и т.д. пока функция php (например, preg_match_all()) не перестанет находить вхождения?

Comment: Если вы о второй части комментария - да, именно так. Если о первой - нет, регулярные выражения поддерживают рекурсию, и(не уверен что именно ваш синтаксис переварит) по идее можно выдернуть нужный вам массив одной единственной регуляркой.

Comment: Владимир, я понял идею, спасибо. С рекурсивными регулярными выражениями вообще не знаком - надо почитать будет. Попробую сделать функцию парсера, если что дельное получиться, поделюсь здесь.

Comment: Владимир, пытаюсь написать регулярное выражение такое '~<!-- begin-(.*?) -->(.*?)<!-- end-(.*?) -->~s', но проблема в том, что оно берет самый первый тег. А мне надо, чтобы он брал совпадение из первой группировки. Вы не подскажете как такое можно провернуть. Отредактировал немного пример строки в теме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось такое регулярное выражение:

```
'~<!-- begin-(.*?) -->(.*?)<!-- end-(\1) -->~sg'
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/FK5bnZ/1